# Select * vs Select count(*), which one is faster to count row?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

My database is MySQL 5.6 and InnoDB engine.
(Assume that the application counts when using `select *`)

I usually used `select count(*)` to count rows.
But when I checked the `Duration` time in `MySQLWorkbench`, `SELECT *` is faster than `SELECT COUNT(*)`.
It can depend on `cache`, but I'm not sure.

In fact, which one is faster and better?

Comment: If you count row in a particular table you can go with `count(1)`

Comment: I didn't realize that `MySQLWorkbench` add `limit 0,1000` on the back. Thank you for you guys reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select count(*)` **is faster than** `select *`:

`select *` scan all the rows:

[image]

If your table have index, mysql query optimizer use index for `select count(*)`:

[image]

And `select *` will take all columns out.
like this example, it took **67.7ms** to take all the datas;

however, `select count(*)` only took **9.2ms** to take the count.

Answer (score 2):

`select count(*)` *should* be faster.  There might be some cases where the execution times are comparable.

But . . .

- `select *` needs to return all the rows to the application.  Each row requires effort and space.
- `select *` must reed all the data.
- `select count(*)` can use an index (if available) smaller than the table.

I cannot think of any normal case where I would expect `select *` to be faster *on a table* than `select count(*)`.  There may be situations with a view where the optimizer gets confused.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` should normally be faster.

Both queries have to do the same processing of the table data to find the matching rows. But `SELECT *` also has to send all the rows back to the client, while `SELECT COUNT(*)` just sends one value back.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` use   `SELECT COUNT(one_column_Name)`